# i can't Merge two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

i have one tables attendance
[main table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjjkZ.png)
 i created 2 views from attendance table attend view and leaved view
view:attend

```
select `dbtest`.`employee`.`empId` AS `empId`,`dbtest`.`attendance`.`timeAttendnace` AS `timeAttendnace` from (`dbtest`.`employee` left join `dbtest`.`attendance` on(`dbtest`.`attendance`.`empId` = `dbtest`.`employee`.`empId` and `dbtest`.`attendance`.`statusAttendnace` = 'In'))
```

view:leaved

```
select `dbtest`.`employee`.`empId` AS `empId`,`dbtest`.`attendance`.`timeAttendnace` AS `timeAttendnace` from (`dbtest`.`employee` left join `dbtest`.`attendance` on(`dbtest`.`attendance`.`empId` = `dbtest`.`employee`.`empId` and `dbtest`.`attendance`.`statusAttendnace` = 'Out'))
```

after that i used this code to merge attend and leaved view

```
select `attend`.`empId` AS `empId`,`attend`.`timeAttendnace` AS `clockIn`,`leaved`.`timeAttendnace` AS `clockOut` from (`dbtest`.`attend` join `dbtest`.`leaved` on(`attend`.`empId` = `leaved`.`empId`)) group by `attend`.`timeAttendnace` order by `attend`.`empId`
```

the result was like this
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZYVr.png)

i need each employee has attend time and leaved time in same day

Comment: Add sample data from the table with your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following query will return you employee wise daily In and Out Time in a single row.

```
SELECT 
cast(TimeAttendence AS DATE),
empid,
MIN(CASE WHEN StatusAttendence = 'In' THEN TimeAttendence END) InTime,
MAX(CASE WHEN StatusAttendence = 'Out' THEN TimeAttendence END) OutTime
FROM main_table
GROUP BY cast(TimeAttendence AS DATE),empid
```